# Why is res.header() not working in express?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, http-headers

I am trying to authenticate a user for login. However, I don't manage to send a response header.
**Login function**

```
// POST /users/login
router.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
    const user = await User.findByCredentials(body.email, body.password);
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
    req.session['token'] =  'Bearer ' + token;
    req.session['user'] =  user;
    // the following line does not seem to work properly
    res.header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token).send(user); 
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "Nutzerdaten sind nicht korrekt" });
  }
});
```

**Axios plugin**

```
$axios.onResponse(res => {
    console.log(res.headers) // does not return an authorization header
    if (res.headers.authorization) {
      store.commit('auth/SET_TOKEN', res.headers.authorization)
    }
    return res
  })
```

**console.log(res.headers)**

```
'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  vary: 'Origin',
  'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '2',
  etag: 'W/"2-l9Fw4VUO7kr8CvBlt4zaMCqXZ0w"',
  date: 'Tue, 30 Jul 2019 12:35:00 GMT',
  connection: 'keep-alive'
```

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: Express v4.x
Do it like `res.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)` then send response in next line `res.send(user)`

Comment: @mabc224 Thank you for your comment. That did not solve the problem.

Comment: .send is the property of res not res.header. try to send in next line.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. `res.header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token); res.send(user);` does not work either.

Comment: @kampfkuchen I tested it before providing solution here, Even official documentation is saying same and providing example which i wrote in my earlier comment `https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send`